# Attach a Custom Post Type to a Woocommerc product as a variation or add-on

Tags: custom-post-types, woocommerce-offtopic, subscription

I am building a website where the users will post their events. In order to highlight the event or promote it on the homepage they will need to buy a subscription and attach it to the event they've published. Once the subscription will be expired, the event will be not more highlighted. So this subscription should be attached somehow to a Custom Post Type called "event".

I am thinking that Woocommerce Subscription plugin is a good thing, but how attach the event to it when user buys the subscription, I can't find a way.

Will be happy for any help or advice, thank you!

Comment: You can add the product_id in a custom field and use that id for showing product details